# Begin form doesn't submit inherited viewmodel ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this case:

```
[Serializable]
public class FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel
{
    public CorteReligacao CorteReligacao { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class OrdensFinalizadasViewModel : FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel
{
    public Manutencao Manutencao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }

    public OrdensFinalizadasViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

so my child here is `OrdensFinalizadasViewModel`. I have this:

```
@model ProjetoPath.OrdensFinalizadasViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Buscar", "OrdensFinalizadas", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "FormBuscarOrdensFinalizadas" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_FormBusca.cshtml", Model)
}
```

And my controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Buscar(OrdensFinalizadasViewModel modelOrdensFinalizadas)
    {
        //DO STUFF
    }
```

what I want is to have access to `CorteReligacao` of `FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel`. But its only filled with `OrdensFinalizadasViewModel` properties.

My view `~/Views/Shared/_FormBusca.cshtml`:

```
@using Capgemini.Telemetria.STCortes.Domain.ViewModel.Common
@model Capgemini.Telemetria.STCortes.Domain.ViewModel.Common.FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel

@{
    var modelOrdensFinalizadas = Model as ProjectPath.OrdensFinalizadasViewModel;
}

<table class="tabela_filtro" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 11px" />
<thead>
 [...]
</thead>
<tbody>
    @if(modelOrdensFinalizadas != null)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    Data
                </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => modelOrdensFinalizadas.DataInicio, new { id = "dataInicio", @class = "campoData", @placeholder = "Data Inicio" })
            </td>
            [...]
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="label_filtro">
                CP
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CorteReligacao.CoreCp, new { style = "width: 20px;" })
            <span class="validation-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CorteReligacao.CoreCp)</span>
        </td>
        [...]
            <input type="image" src="~/Content/img/icons/enviar.gif" value="Buscar" title="Buscar" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is it possible to do that? I'm kinda new on asp.net MVC.
Would appreciate any help / sugestion.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

in your view you are telling it that your model is type `FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel`.  If you change that to

```
@using Capgemini.Telemetria.STCortes.Domain.ViewModel.Common
@model Capgemini.Telemetria.STCortes.Domain.ViewModel.Common.OrdensFinalizadasViewModel
```

and delete this section

```
@{
    var modelOrdensFinalizadas = Model as ProjectPath.OrdensFinalizadasViewModel;
}
```

you should be able to use

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CorteReligacao.CoreCp, new { style = "width: 20px;" })
```

you need to change your textboxfor to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataInicio, new { id = "dataInicio", @class = "campoData", @placeholder = "Data Inicio" })
```

have you tried adding constructors to your models to initialize the child properties?

```
[Serializable]
public class FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel
{
    public FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel()
    {
        CorteReligacao = new CorteReligacao();
    }
    public CorteReligacao CorteReligacao { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class OrdensFinalizadasViewModel : FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel
{
    public Manutencao Manutencao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataFim { get; set; }

    public OrdensFinalizadasViewModel()
        : base()
    {
        Manutencao = new Manutencao();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey buddy. Thanks for your answer! However I can already access `CorteReligacao` using the "father" entity. The problem is that the child object gets null on controller-side everytime I try to post child and father togheter.

Comment: thats a strange one.. i added a suggestion to add constructors but that doesn't always work..

Comment: yeh the `: base()` is redudant.... I still tryed but didn't work. Yet I tryed to add on controller method a new paramter: `public ActionResult Buscar(OrdensFinalizadasViewModel modelOrdensFinalizadas, CorteReligacao corteReligacao)` and the `CorteReligacao` gets filled but not as a child of `OrdensFinalizadasViewModel`

Comment: stumped me then.. i could create a dotnetfiddle with an example of how it should work but that probably wont help much since you're doing some different things in your partial view

Answer (score 0):

yes is possible, just I recommend you a few changes

first:
delete from your partial view

```
         @{
         var modelOrdensFinalizadas = Model as          ProjectPath.OrdensFinalizadasViewModel;
       }
```

changes this from your partial to your view and delete it from partial, rename modelOrdensFinalizadas  to Model,

```
      <table class="tabela_filtro" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 11px" />
       <thead>

        [...]

     </thead>
    <tbody>
         @if(Model!= null)
         {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>
                Data
            </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.DataInicio, new  { id = "dataInicio", @class = "campoData", @placeholder = "Data Inicio" })
        </td>
        [...]
    </tr>
}
<tr>
     //here your partial view
     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_FormBusca.cshtml", Model)
          </tr>
  </tbody>
```

and then in your partial view just put the resto of the table that you need

```
    <td>
        <label class="label_filtro">
            CP
        </label>
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CorteReligacao.CoreCp, new { style = "width: 20px;" })
        <span class="validation-message">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CorteReligacao.CoreCp)</span>
    </td>
    [...]
        <input type="image" src="~/Content/img/icons/enviar.gif" value="Buscar" title="Buscar" />
    </td>
```

and now in you controller you will have access to the model(OrdensFinalizadasViewModel and FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel)

you are getting null in you controller because

```
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => modelOrdensFinalizadas.DataInicio
```

is not part of the model (FormBuscarCorteReligacaoViewModel) in the partial view

hope this can help you or at least give you an idea